# Prevent standard user from formatting and ejecting removable NTFS drive on Windows 10

Tags: windows, partitioning, external-hard-drive, administrator, group-policy

I have a removable NTFS hard drive attached to a computer by USB for backup purposes. I have the drive partition of importance blocked from non-admin accounts using security under properties. The standard user account owner cannot access the drive using this method, but they still have the ability to format any of the partitions of the drive by right clicking and selecting format. I had assumed that there would be some control over whether or not non-admins would be able to do this through GPO, but that isn't the case. There is a group policy setting ("Devices: Allowed to format and eject removable media"), but that doesn't work.

Outside of hiding the drive partitions through group policy or regedit, I cannot seem to find a solution to this problem. I wanted to avoid this because I didn't want to go to the hassle of setting this up for drive letters that are not A-D (group policy by default has a setting that only hides those). I cannot use the remove drive letter option through disk management because I'm using Macrium Reflect to save backup images to this external drive so the admin account needs to see the drives. Doing some research online, there are people who are saying that only administrators can format or eject NTFS drives, but I don't think that applies to Windows 10 or removable drives at least. I've been able to recreate this situation using another Windows 10 PC, so I know it's not limited to just the computer I've been trying to set up restrictions.

Any solutions to this or should I move forward with using GPO settings or regedit to hide the drive from the non-admin user?

Comment: This process is hard until you apply per-user registry settings to restrict user to write into the USB flash drive, which will also prevent them to format it. But still the user will be unable to write in the USB drive. Also for ejecting the flash drive, I can't recommend anything, as I the user can just plug off the USB drive from the ports and it is unstoppable.

Comment: I'm not too concerned with someone physically unplugging the hard drive. That's something I cannot really block, but I want to prevent them from ejecting the hard drive by mistake. My main concern though is the ability for a standard user to format this hard drive. I keep reading information online that non-admins should not be able to format NTFS drives, but I'm guessing this is not applicable for Windows 10 or a USB hard drive? I'm not sure. I think my best option is to probably hide the hard drive using group policy. I've seen how to do this, but was hoping there was another solution.

Comment: A device can only be injected if it is no longer in use. Therefore a small service running background that keeps some handles to the disk open should be enough to prevent any attempts to eject that drive. Not sure if this also works for formatting. Additionally I would mount the drive not as drive-letter but in to a sub-directory where the user does not have NTFS permissions to view the drive.

Comment: Robert, I considered mounting it as a sub-directory too, but I saw some issues with that. Would this run into conflict with Macrium backups? I don't think it would be able to see that the folder I point as the location for saving the backup file is a mount point for an external drive. If it assumes that it is the location of the main C: drive that is being backed up, it will not allow it as a save directory.